# How to get column value comparison in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below. The table holds the price of a product for each day in a year. I would like to get price change for each day by year.

```
Product   Year    1Jan     2Jan .................... 31Dec
A         2018    10       20   .................... 120
A         2019    130      150  .................... 200 
B         2018    15       23   .................... 90
B         2019    113      130  .................... 220
```

I would like to compare columns sequentially with year overlaps and get output as below.

•   For the year 2018, by negating the value 2 Jan from 1 Jan (2 Jan-1 Jan), we get the new value of 2 Jan.

•   For the year 2018, by negating the value 3Jan from 2 Jan (3 Jan-2 Jan), we get the new value of 3 Jan.

•   For the year 2018, by negating the value 31Dec from 30 Dec (31 Dec-30 Dec), we get the new value of 31 Dec

•   Now, For the year 2019, by negating the value 31 Dec(2018 year) from 1 Jan (2019 year), we get the new value of 1 Jan, 2019

So, in a nutshell, the value of a column is the difference of its value with previous day value.

```
Product   Year    1Jan     2Jan .................... 31Dec
A         2018    10       10   .................... 15       (just assume value of 30Dec column is 105)
A         2019    10       20   .................... 10       (just assume value of 30Dec column is 190)
B         2018    15       8    .................... 8        (just assume value of 30Dec column is 82)
B         2019    23       17   .................... 10       (just assume value of 30Dec column is 210)
```

Let me know, if things are not clear.

Comment: You mean you have a column for each day of the year?

Comment: probably OT but i see a potential bad design here. How can you have 365 columns in a table (1 for each day) ?

Comment: So you have a table with 365 columns? Awesome!

Comment: What about the column 29Feb and its values in non leap-years? This design is somehting you should change - if possible,,,

Comment: @SalmanA : Dont get confused with example, the example is just for scenario purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Though logically there is nothing in this query, but still you have to work hard to write it -

```
SELECT Product
      ,Year
      ,1Jan
      ,2Jan - 1Jan 2Jan
      ,3Jan - 2Jan 3Jan
      .
      .
      .
      ,31Dec - 30Dec 31Dec
FROM YOUR_TAB
ORDER BY Product
        ,Year;
```

Comment: @AshishBhagasra, My name is Ankit Bajpai.

Comment: 1Jan should be " 1Jan- LAG(31Dec) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY date) AS Jan1". Rest are OK. Thanks All. This was easy :P

Answer (score 0):

first of all I think the design of the table could be better but thats a topic for some other time. Right now below code should work -

```
SELECT Product, Year,  
       1Jan      AS '1st Jan',  
       2Jan-1Jan AS '2nd Jan',  
       3Jan-2Jan AS '3rd Jan',  
       4Jan-3Jan AS '4th Jan',  
       .  
       .  
       .  
       .   
       .  
       31Dec-30Dec AS '31st Dec',

FROM [table name];
```